# VBA - finding last used row in a column

Tags: excel, vba

Given a sheet like this: 
https://ethercalc.org/l3czk4zwfhek

I want to compute the row # of the last used cell in my column.

My code:

```
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
```

Seems not to work. What would be the correct way of doing this? UsedRange seems not to work either.

Comment: That returns `30` as the last used row for me.  Is that not what it returns for you?  What value are you expecting instead?  It's possible that you'd need to qualify range references with a sheet, like: `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Seems like you were right, I needed to add a sheet to my range references in this case. Thanks!